# Is metadata is stored in every node of Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, cassandra-2.1

In a Cassandra cluster, Let suppose Cassandra cluster have Node A, B and C. Then will Node A have all the metadata information of Node B & C also? and vice versa?

Will we have any separate node which possesses the metadata information of all the other Nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `system` (and `system_schema` in recent versions) keyspace[s] holds the metadata on each node that they keep in sync with a different mechanism. If you look at the schema for those keyspaces:

```
# describe keyspace system;

CREATE KEYSPACE system WITH replication = {'class': 'LocalStrategy'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

You can see the `LocalStrategy` replication strategy which means that mutations to it are not distributed but just applied on the local node. Gossip is used for identifying if nodes have out of date schemas and kicking off updates.

All the data not related to schemas, and which nodes own what tokens are all really only relevant to that node and not distributed in any way. For example `compactions_in_progress` are just for that nodes compactions. Other nodes compactions or the state of its sstables are irrelevant to other nodes.

Comment: What about the cassandra.yaml file will it be present in every node and holds all the configuration details of that particular node??

Comment: that holds configuration, not state. but yes its on each node.